# Redefinition of variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

The execution of this script: tmp.js, that contains:

```
var parameters = {};
(1,eval)("var parameters = {a:1}");
(1,eval)(console.log(parameters));

node tmp.js
```

produces:

```
{}
```

If we comment out the first statement, and execute again the script, we obtain:

```
{ a: 1 }
```

The global scope contains exactly the same variables with the same value, so why console.log displays a different value?

Comment: That last line was probably meant to be either `console.log(parameters)` or `(1,eval)("console.log(parameters)")`. But don't change it now, it would invalidate the answers you've received.

Answer (score 5):

Because all code you run in Node is running in a [Node module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html),¹ with its own scope, **not** at global scope. But the way you're calling `eval` (indirectly, `(1,eval)(...)`) runs the code in the string at global scope. So you have **two** `parameters` variables: A local one in the module, and a global one. The local one wins (when it exists).

```
var parameters = {};                // <== Creates a local variable in the module
(1,eval)("var parameters = {a:1}"); // <== Creates a global variable
(1,eval)(console.log(parameters));  // <== Shows the local if there is one,
                                    //     the global if not
```

Your last line of code is a bit odd: It calls `console.log`, passing in `parameters`, and then passes the return value (which will be `undefined`) into `eval`. Not much point in that call to `eval` with `undefined.`

**If** that last line were

```
(1,eval)("console.log(parameters)");
```

...it would run at global scope, not module scope, and always show the global.

Here's an example that does the same thing without Node:

```js
(function() {
  var parameters = {};
  (1,eval)("var parameters = {a:1}");
  console.log("local", parameters);
  (1,eval)('console.log("global", parameters);');
})();
```

---

¹ FWIW, according to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), your code is wrapped in a function that looks like this:

```
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
// Module code actually lives in here
});
```

...and then executed by Node.